# Plone error: This page does not seem to exist…

Tags: plone

I am new to Plone and I just installed version 4.3.5. Everything works fine except for viewing uploaded files (PDF, PNG, Word, Excel, etc). When I click on the file link to view it, I get the following error: This page does not seem to exist…

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: The page doesn't look to exist. What have you done to figure out it exists?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue affecting file downloads in Plone 4.3.5. You can downgrade to Plone 4.3.4, or wait for Plone 4.3.6 to be released.

Answer (score 1):

First check basic things...

1. Checkout the **link** which is hitting your file is correct or not.
2. If Link is correct then see your configuration that actually hitting your file class.
3. If Link is hitting your file then to check its correctly hitting your **class** debbug it.

just print anything under **__call__()** method of class.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to, in your buildout, pin the latest plone.app.blob:

```
plone.app.blob = 1.5.15
```